# Photo Upload together with some data won't work. I used batch_insert in my model

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This is the View.php file

```
<input name="u_code[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
<input name="u_name[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
<input name="u_address[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
<input name="photo[]" required="required" style="margin:0px; ">
```

This is my Controller inserting multiple data but I want to include upload photo.Unfortunately it will not run.

My table has a field for User ID, User Code, Username, User address the lastly the photo of each user.

```
    function user_add()
    {
    if ($_POST) 
    {
        $u_id =$this->input->post('u_id');
        $u_code =$this->input->post('u_code');
        $u_name =$this->input->post('u_name');
        $u_address = $this->input->post('u_address');

                                if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name']))
        {
            $upload = $this->_do_upload();
            $data['photo'] = $upload;
        }        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('u_id')); $i++)
        {

            $data[$i] = array(
                'u_id' => $u_id[$i],
                'u_code' => $u_code[$i],
                'u_name' => $u_name[$i],
                'u_address' => $u_address[$i],

            );
        }
            $insert = $this->user_model->user_add($data);
            echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
    }



This part is the function to upload photo.



public function photo_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path']          = 'upload/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100; //set max size allowed in Kilobyte
    $config['max_width']            = 1000; // set max width image allowed
    $config['max_height']           = 1000; // set max height allowed
    $config['file_name']            = round(microtime(true) * 1000); //just milisecond timestamp fot unique name

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->photo_upload('photo')) //upload and validate
    {
        $data['inputerror'][] = 'photo';
        $data['error_string'][] = 'Upload error: '.$this->upload->display_errors('',''); //show ajax error
        $data['status'] = FALSE;
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    }
    return $this->upload->data('file_name');
}

**Model:**
    public function user_add($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert_batch($this->table, $data);

        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

[This is the Actual forms picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/918uT.jpg)

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Comment: Reading the code, I can see bug in `$data = array();` because wether or not there is an image to be uploaded (`if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name']))`) with this initialization you are overriding `$data['photo']` variable. Try, after `if` block, to set `else` block `else { $data = [] }`.

Comment: Thank you Tpojka, but still doesn't work